# Combining OpenGL ES and View-Based Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

How to combine OpenGL ES application with a View-Based Application for iPhone?

Comment: I really like the dramamtic accent on this post... :D

Answer (score 0):

You really just link the two together by switching the view in UIWindow.

```
[window addSubview:yourView];
```

It really is that easy. You just can't mix OpenGL ES and UIView drawing within the same view, unless you stop OpenGL ES animating of course.